# Gtk, passing strings with user_data

Tags: c, gtk

I create popup context menu with rightclick at runtime, from treeview, based on words in selected sentence. Code:

```
//---- inpropper ------------
gboolean
menu_RELEASE(GtkWidget *menu, gpointer *user_data)
{
   printf("released at %s\n", (char*)user_data);
   return FALSE;
}
//---------------------------

//---- propper [SOLVED] -----
gboolean
menu_RELEASE(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer user_data)
{
   gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry1), (char*)user_data);
   gtk_widget_grab_focus(entry1);
   return FALSE;
}
//--------------------------

GtkWidget *create_art_menu(GtkWidget *button)
{
   char *ntext;
   treesel = gtk_tree_view_get_selection(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view));
if (gtk_tree_selection_get_selected(treesel, &model ,&iter))
{
    gtk_tree_model_get(model, &iter, cNaziv, &ntext, -1);

    GtkWidget *menu, *menu_item;
    menu = gtk_menu_new();

    char *sresult = NULL;
    sresult = strtok(ntext, " ");
    while(sresult != NULL)
    {
        if (strlen(sresult)>1)
        {
            menu_item = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label(sresult);
            gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), menu_item);
            g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(menu_item), "button-release-event", G_CALLBACK(menu_RELEASE), (gpointer)sresult);
        }
        sresult = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    gtk_menu_attach_to_widget(GTK_MENU(menu), button, NULL);
    gtk_widget_show_all(menu);
    return menu;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Signals are triggered and passes OK but I can't get string of clicked menu item in menu_RELEASE handler from user_data which I need for further action.

Q: How to get string of released menu item in menu_RELEASE handler based on showed code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the signature of callback which is connected to `button-release-event` is incorrect. The signature should be [`gboolean  user_function(GtkWidget *widget,GdkEvent  *event, gpointer  user_data)`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-button-release-event). Try changing `gboolean menu_RELEASE(GtkWidget *menu, gpointer *user_data)` to `gboolean menu_RELEASE(GtkWidget *menu, GdkEvent *event, gpointer *user_data)`.
Alternatively, you can use [`g_signal_connect_swapped`](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect-swapped) instead of `g_signal_connect` & change `gboolean menu_RELEASE(GtkWidget *menu, gpointer *user_data)` to `gboolean menu_RELEASE(gpointer *user_data)`
Additonally, be wary of what @Joachim Pileborg has already mention regarding `strtok`.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. All I have to do is change declaration on your's first advice and now my code works as expected. Now I have choosen text in my gtkentry!

Answer (score 1):

The result returned by the `strtok` function is a pointer to an internal static buffer, that will get overwritten on each call. If you want to save the result for use later, you have to create a duplicate (e.g. with the `strdup` function).

But watch out, doing this needs you to free the new string when done with it. for example if you remove the menu item, you need to free this buffer as well.

Comment: Is it so visible that I'm still fighting with C basics?:) Thanks for advice, simple solution from first suggestion works perfect!

Comment: @user973238 Don't worry. We were all beginners once. :)